# Why Dynamically loading resources using html imports does not require an entry in web_accessible_resources?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Without my chrome extension, it appears that I am able to load resources into the document's head that are not specified in `web_accessible_resources`.

I would like some clarification as to whether this is a bug that will come back to hunt me once it's fixed or a feature in a chrome extension.

Without further ado, this is how I am loading the resources from my `content script`

```
  function loadRes(res) {
    return new Promise(
      function(resolve, reject) {
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.setAttribute('rel', 'import');
        link.setAttribute('href', res);
        link.onload = function() {
          resolve(res);
        };
        document.head.appendChild(link);
      });
  }

  loadRes( "vendor/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js" )
  .then( loadRes("vendor/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html") )
  .then(function(){
      window.chromeApp = new ChromeApp(options);
  });
}
```

Can anyone explain why doesn't chrome restrict these from loading dynamically?

**UPDATE**

Here is my manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "Web Notes",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "C",
  "icons": {"128": "assets/images/ext_icon.png"},
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "assets/images/ext_icon.png",
    "default_title": "C",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [
      "vendor/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "vendor/bower_components/underscore/underscore-min.js",
      "vendor/bower_components/backbone/backbone.js",
      "vendor/bower_components/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js",

      "assets/javascripts/collections/asset_collection.js",

      "assets/javascripts/helpers/asset_view_helper.js",
      "assets/javascripts/models/pouch_db_user.js",
      "assets/javascripts/models/node_client.js",
      "assets/javascripts/views/chrome_app.js",

      "content.js"
    ],
    "css": [
      "vendor/bower_components/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.css",
      "vendor/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "assets/stylesheets/css/chrome_app.css"
    ],
    "matches": ["file://*", "http://localhost/*.*"]
  }],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "vendor/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.map",
    "assets/images/*.*",
    "web_components/component/component.html"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are the resources content scripts? Content scripts themselves do not need to be whitelisted.

Comment: The resources I'm loading are not specified in my ``manifest.json`` So I'm not sure if they would be considered content scripts. However, the executing script above IS A CONTENT SCRIPT. Also note that one of these resources is not a script at all but rather an html file.

Comment: Could you please attach the manifest file?

Comment: Just a quick review, there's two faults with your manifest. First remove `,` after `"assets/stylesheets/css/chrome_app.css",` Second the JSON should all be data, and if you include a comment, then it will be data too. It doesn't support type of `//` comment.

Comment: I apologized, right before posting the manifest I realized there was an unnecessary file in their and removed it, hence the extra coma. That aside I removed the comments as well and reloaded my extension and as expected, I'm still able to load scripts into the head.

Comment: It sounds like a bug to me now. I think you'd better file it in [crbug.com](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).

Comment: I filed a bug here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=485780&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified